# Having trouble getting servo to work

Tags: transmitter, receiver, servo, flysky

I am extremely new to the whole diy rc thing, so please just bear with me.

I am trying to make an rc boat, and have purchased a flysky receiver and transmitter for it. I plugged in my battery and servo, and nothing happened. Tried a different receiver, still no servo movement. Tried re-binding, different channels, servos, you name it, I can't seem to get the servos to move.

Any ideas on why its not working?